# Combine rows with duplicate values and display updated table

Tags: mysql, group-concat

My shopping cart exports a csv file which I load into a database.  A given order can be for multiple items.  There is a separate row for each item ordered. So I end up with for example 3 identical rows all with the same order number.  All the fields in the rows have exactly the same values except for the item field.

So for example I have this:

Key         OrderNumber            Items                Name             Address

1                           1                               Car                     Joe             12 Cat Street

2                          1                              Truck                 Joe             12 Cat Street

3                           1                              Van                     Joe             12 Cat Street

4                           2                             Plane                 Jim             35 Dog Street

5                           2                             Bike                    Jim             35 Dog Street

6                           3                             Boat                   Tom            18 Pig Street

The complete table has many more fields.  I can use a select statement with group_concat but it only shows me the OrderNumber and Items fields.  I would like to generate a complete table with all fields showing that concatenates the items according to OrderNumber.  So it would look like this:

Key         OrderNumber            Items                         Name             Address

1                           1                           Car,Truck,Van                Joe             12 Cat Street

2                          2                              Plane,Bike                     Jim           35 Dog Street

3                           3                              Van                                 Tom           18 Pig Street


Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the query you want?

```
select (@rn := @rn + 1) as key, OrderNumber,
       group_concat(items) as items, name, address
from table t cross join (select @rn := 0) params
group by OrderNumber, name, address;
```

Comment: Yes, that is basically it but I get a syntax error on the key.

Comment: This works: select  OrderNumber,
       group_concat(ID SEPARATOR ', ' ) as ID, DeliverToName, DeliverToAddress
from table1 
group by OrderNumber, DeliverToAddress, DeliverToName ; <br>

Comment: This works perfectly but it doesn't include the key:                                                   select  OrderNumber,
       group_concat(ID SEPARATOR ', ' ) as ID, DeliverToName, DeliverToAddress from table1 
group by OrderNumber, DeliverToAddress, DeliverToName ;                              I get a syntax error on the key field.  It won't let me include it in the query for some reason.

Comment: I got it to work.  I was missing the "Key" quotes.  Key is a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the "Key" quotes.  Key is a reserved word.

Thanks for the help!